# how to avoid sub query on mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

there is 4 table

```
team
---------------
id | teamname |
1  | lal      |
2  | sobuj    |

member
-----------------------
id | membername| team |
1  | sagor     | 1    |
2  | sumon     | 1    |

dps
---------------------------------------------------
id | member| team | deposit | refund | ddate      |
1  | 1     | 1    | 100     | 12     | 2016-09-01 |
2  | 2     | 1    | 120     | 34     | 2016-09-01 |
3  | 1     | 1    | 130     | 22     | 2016-09-01 |
4  | 3     | 1    | 120     | 0      | 2016-09-01 |

mvs
----------------------------------------------------
id | member| team | mvs_total| refund | ddate      |
1  | 1     | 1    | 100      | 12     | 2016-09-01 |
2  | 2     | 1    | 120      | 34     | 2016-09-01 |
3  | 1     | 1    | 130      | 22     | 2016-09-01 |
4  | 3     | 1    | 120      | 0      | 2016-09-01 |
```

here is my query:

```
$result=mysql_query(select * from member where team='1');
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
do{
    $aresult=mysql_query(select sum(deposit)-sum(refund)as balance from dps where member='$row[id]');
    $arow=mysql_fetch_array($aresult);
    echo $arow[balance];

    $bresult=mysql_query(select sum(mvs_total)as mvs_balance from mvs where member='$row[id]' and date1<='2016-09-01');
    $brow=mysql_fetch_array($bresult);
    echo $brow[mvs_total];

} while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

its taking too much time how to avoid sub query or how can i save time advice plz Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any subquery here

Comment: mysql is deprecated now,  use PDO or mysqli

Comment: actually i want to avoid query in loop 
i would like to use join like 
`SELECT member.mname, member.fn, loan.member, sum( loan.deposit )  - sum( loan.withdraw )  AS balance, sum( loan.deposit2 )  - sum( loan.withdraw2 )  AS balance2, sum( loan.total )  - sum( loan.lpay )  AS outsstanding
FROM loan
JOIN member ON ( loan.member = member.id ) 
WHERE loan.team =  '10'
AND loan.cs =  'Core'
GROUP  BY member`

Comment: You're doing 2 queries for each row in your first query, of course it's taking too much time. Try using `group by`

Comment: You should use join to avoid sub queries. try to make relationship between tables and use the join statements to fetch data from diff tables. For more information please refer the below links :
[http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I notice in your table structure is that **repetition of column**.
E.g. **team** column not require in **dps** and **mcs** table, because from **member** column **[connect to member table]** you can easily find dps or mvs is under which team.

For your current problem you can use following query.

```
    SELECT member.id, 
       member.membername, 
       Sum(dps.deposit) - Sum(dps.refund)       AS balance, 
       Sum(mvs.mvs_total)                       AS mvs_balance, 
       Sum(loan.deposit) - Sum(loan.withdraw)   AS balance, 
       Sum(loan.deposit2) - Sum(loan.withdraw2) AS balance2, 
       Sum(loan.total) - Sum(loan.lpay)         AS outsstanding 
FROM   member AS member 
       LEFT JOIN dps AS dps 
              ON dps.member = member.id 
       LEFT JOIN mvs AS mvs 
              ON mvs.member = member.id 
       LEFT JOIN loan AS loan 
              ON loan.member = member.id 
       WHERE  member.team = 1 
       AND mvs.ddate <= '2016-09-01' 
       -- AND loan.team = '10'  
       -- AND loan.cs = 'Core' 
GROUP  BY member.id
```

Comment: hello your ans is right but i would like to view group by member i am adding group by loan.member but it not working